# Issue in jquery dobpicker.js

Tags: jquery

I am using DOB Picker (https://github.com/tyea/dobpicker) for selecting dates in my web application, I set the date to current day when the page loads

```
$.dobPicker({
        daySelector: '#selectedday', /* Required */
        monthSelector: '#selectedmonth', /* Required */
        yearSelector: '#selectedyear', /* Required */
        dayDefault: 'Day', /* Optional */
        monthDefault: 'Month', /* Optional */
        yearDefault: 'Year', /* Optional */
    });
    
    
    $("#selectedday").val((new Date).getDate());
    var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
    $("#selectedmonth").val((("0" + currentMonth).slice(-2)).toString());
    $("#selectedyear").val((new Date).getFullYear().toString());
```

When the date is changed then based on the date, the months disabled (if we select 31 then for example August month is disabled, we cannot select it), How can I disable the months based on the date selected in the page load itself? For example if selected date is July 31, then in the page load itself I need to disable invalid months (the months which has no 31).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$("#selectedday").change();` after `$("#selectedday").val((new Date).getDate());` line which will trigger `change` event for `selectedday` input. Rest will be taken care by `dobPicker`.

Your code would be like below.

```
$("#selectedday").val((new Date).getDate());
$("#selectedday").change(); // <-- Add this code to trigger click event of selectedday.
var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
$("#selectedmonth").val((("0" + currentMonth).slice(-2)).toString());
$("#selectedyear").val((new Date).getFullYear().toString());
```

Try it below.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $.dobPicker({
    daySelector: '#selectedday',  /* Required */
    monthSelector: '#selectedmonth',  /* Required */
    yearSelector: '#selectedyear',  /* Required */
    dayDefault: 'Day',  /* Optional */
    monthDefault: 'Month',  /* Optional */
    yearDefault: 'Year',  /* Optional */
  });

debugger;
  $("#selectedday").val((new Date).getDate());      
  $("#selectedday").change(); // <-- Add this code to trigger click event of selectedday.
  var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
  $("#selectedmonth").val((("0" + currentMonth).slice(-2)).toString());
  $("#selectedyear").val((new Date).getFullYear());
});


jQuery.extend({

    dobPicker: function (params) {

        // apply defaults
        if (typeof(params.dayDefault) == "undefined") {
            params.dayDefault = "Day";
        }
        if (typeof(params.monthDefault) == "undefined"){
            params.monthDefault = "Month";
        }
        if (typeof(params.yearDefault) == "undefined") {
            params.yearDefault = "Year";
        }
        if (typeof(params.minimumAge) == "undefined") {
            params.minimumAge = 18;
        }
        if (typeof(params.maximumAge) == "undefined") {
            params.maximumAge = 100;
        }

        // find elements
        var dayElement = $(params.daySelector);
        var monthElement = $(params.monthSelector);
        var yearElement = $(params.yearSelector);

        // set days
        dayElement.append("<option value=\"\">" + params.dayDefault + "</option>");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
            var day = "" + i;
            var value = i > 9 ? "" + i : "0" + i;
            dayElement.append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + day + "</option>");
        }

        // set months
        var months = [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ];
        monthElement.append("<option value=\"\">" + params.monthDefault + "</option>");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            var month = months[i - 1];
            var value = i > 9 ? "" + i : "0" + i;
            monthElement.append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + month + "</option>");
        }

        // set years
        var now = (new Date()).getFullYear();
        var minimum = now - params.minimumAge;
        var maximum = minimum - params.maximumAge;
        yearElement.append("<option value=\"\">" + params.yearDefault + "</option>");
        for (i = minimum; i >= maximum; i--) {
            var year = "" + i;
            var value = year;
            yearElement.append("<option value=\"" + value + "\">" + year + "</option>");
        }

        // disable months
        dayElement.change(function () {

            monthElement.selectedIndex = 0;
            yearElement.selectedIndex = 0;
            yearElement.find("option").removeAttr("disabled");

            var day = parseInt(dayElement.val());

            if (day >= 1 && day <= 29) {
                monthElement.find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else if (day == 30) {
                monthElement.find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
                monthElement.find("option[value=\"02\"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else if(day == 31) {
                monthElement.find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
                monthElement.find("option[value=\"02\"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                monthElement.find("option[value=\"04\"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                monthElement.find("option[value=\"06\"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                monthElement.find("option[value=\"09\"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                monthElement.find("option[value=\"11\"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }

        });

        // disable years
        monthElement.change(function () {

            yearElement.selectedIndex = 0;
            yearElement.find("option").removeAttr("disabled");

            var day = parseInt(dayElement.val());
            var month = parseInt(monthElement.val());

            if (day == 29 && month == 2) {
                yearElement.find("option").each(function (index, value) {
                    if (index > 0) {
                        var option = $(value);
                        var year = parseInt(option.attr("value"));
                        if (year % 4 == 0) {
                            option.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectedday"></select>
<select id="selectedmonth"></select>
<select id="selectedyear"></select>
```

Comment: if we use $("#selectedday").change();, then the month and year will be cleared.

Comment: Move `$("#selectedday").change();` after `$("#selectedday").val((new Date).getDate());` line. It will work as intended. `change` event will `trigger` first after that `selectedmonth` & `selectedyear` will be set. So they won't get cleared.

Comment: and trigger change of selectedmonth after setting month also for checking leap years, thanks.